# String using Character pointer in C

Tags: c, scanf

When I am taking an user input for a senences with even least of one space the character pointer is taking just up to the first blank space only, WHY?
**Please provide an alternative if necessary**

```
char *ptr;
ptr=(char*)malloc(sizeof(char));
scanf("%Ns",ptr);
```

***Edited**

Comment: First of all, you allocate memory for *one* character. To read a string, you need at least *two* (one for the character, one for the *null terminator* that all strings need).

Comment: Why are you casting `malloc` in C? This is bad - please google it

Comment: As for your problem, that's what [`scanf`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) with the `"%s"` format *do*. It reads *space-delimited* "words". If you want to read a whole line I recommend [`fgets`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) instead.

Comment: Lastly, what is that `N` supposed to do in the format string? That's not standard.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude so what shall I do any suggestions?

Comment: @user8458463 I think we have an [XY Problem](http://xyproblem.info/) here.

Comment: I think you should read the manual page for `scanf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `%s` format specifier for `scanf` reads a sequence of **non-whitespace characters.**  That means it stops after reading a space, newline, tab, etc.

Also, you're only allocating space for a single `char`.  That's only enough to store the terminating null byte.  You would need to allocate at least enough space for the number of characters you expect to read, plus one for the null terminator.

If you want to read a full line of text, you should use the `fgets` function.

```
char line[100];
fgets(line, 100, stdin);
// if a newline was stored, remove it
if (strrchr(line, '\n') != NULL) {
    *(strrchr(line, '\n')) = '\0';
}
```